# fflush(stdout) in c

Tags: c, stdout, fflush

Right when I am at fflush(stdout) and I break there in GDB, can I know what is there in stdout before I actually print it?

How can I know what is there in stdout at any point in time?

Comment: I think I didn't explain it well. Basically when my program ends and flushes stdout, I am seeing weird o/p. Thats why I want to monitor stdout all time to see what is being written when and by whom.

Comment: What happens if you switch to unbuffered output with `setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost certainly can, but you probably shouldn't. The standard requires only that `FILE` be a type that is useful to the implementation to identify an open file and whatever state is required to implement the semantics of the various functions that operate on streams.

I'd generally agree with other posters that `fflush()` is a reliable way to know what you actually wrote to the file.

However, if you have lost track of what parts of your code might be writing to a stream, then it can occasionally be useful to watch the stream in action and catch it changing.

In practice, `FILE` is a typedef for a `struct` that is declared by your implementation in the header file stdio.h (often named `struct _iobuf`). Although a typical implementation only lightly documents its members, a typical implementation also implements `putchar()` and some of its friends as macros that are also found in stdio.h. That, combined with the likely availability of sources for the C runtime library of any toolchain you are likely to be using with gdb, gets you all the information you need to peek under the hood.

The stdio.h provided in MinGW GCC 3.4.5 implements `FILE` as follows:

```
typedef struct _iobuf
{
    char*   _ptr;
    int _cnt;
    char*   _base;
    int _flag;
    int _file;
    int _charbuf;
    int _bufsiz;
    char*   _tmpfname;
} FILE;

// oversimplify declaration of _iob[] here for clarity:
extern FILE _iob[FOPEN_MAX];    /* An array of FILE imported from DLL. */
//...
#define STDIN_FILENO    0
#define STDOUT_FILENO   1
#define STDERR_FILENO   2
#define stdin   (&_iob[STDIN_FILENO])
#define stdout  (&_iob[STDOUT_FILENO])
#define stderr  (&_iob[STDERR_FILENO])
```

and implements `putchar()` as an inline function taking advantage of a GCC extension to C:

```
__CRT_INLINE int __cdecl __MINGW_NOTHROW putchar(int __c)
{
  return (--stdout->_cnt >= 0)
    ?  (int) (unsigned char) (*stdout->_ptr++ = (char)__c)
    :  _flsbuf (__c, stdout);}
```

From this you can tell that the end of the buffer is pointed to by the member `_ptr`, and infer that the only other `char *` in `struct _iobuf` (`_base`) is pointing to the beginning of the buffer. The member `_cnt` is clearly the count of unused characters remaining in the buffer. The function `_flsbuf()` must take the first character that didn't fit and put it at the beginning of the buffer after it wrote the current buffer content to the file and restored the `_cnt` field.

So, if you watch `stdout->_base` and `BUFSIZ - stdout->_cnt` you would, for this implementation, have a display of how much and what is in the current buffer.

Answer (score 2):

If you allocate a buffer yourself and pass it to [setvbuf](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/setvbuf/), I suppose you can access it before a flush, since it's yours to begin with.

**EDIT:** Your comment made your intent more clear, but what you want won't be easy:

1. Set up your own buffer as described above,
2. Set a [read watchpoint](http://www.unknownroad.com/rtfm/gdbtut/gdbwatch.html#READ) on `stdout`,
3. Watch your program slow to a crawl.

From then on, `gdb` will break each time *anything* accesses `stdout`, and you can check your buffer for changes, weird output, etc.

That said, that's not an ideal solution at all. A far better approach would be using a logging-enabled output function everywhere in your code.

Comment: One catch: there's no guarantee `setvbuf` will even use the buffer you give it. It may elect only to use it if it's larger than the existing internal buffer, or always ignore it...

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to flush `stdout`, which means basically you are seeing the content on the screen or in a file(if `stdout` is redirected).

Answer (score 0):

use "setbuf()", and keep a handle to the buffer, which you can peek at.  Unfortunately, I don't know off the top how to find the offset and length of unflushed data.